# how to validate a list of ID number contains multiple condition in excel?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have a column in excel that contain ID number of Employer. The ID number is madeup of character and numbers which i need to validate.

```
   ID Number
   VD23CCS
   CS69NNS
   FT8883L
   05TS333
   QJ63T2D
   KW95ALT
```

I want to create another column to validate whether the ID numbers are valid or not. There are conditions which is given in the following.

1. Length of ID number is 7.
2. First 2 positions have characters.
3. Last 3 positions are Characters.
4. 2 positions have numbers in the middle.

If the ID is valid, the corresponding cell will show "Yes" otherwise it will show "No".
I have used Excel formulae such as `=NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(AND(left(A2, 2), RIGHT(A2, 3)))))` But i am not getting the expected output.

The following table is the expected table output.

```
   ID Number.     Validation(Yes/No)
   VD23CCS        Yes
   CS69NNS        Yes
   FT8883L        No
   05TS333        No
   QJ63T2D        No
   KW95ALT        Yes
```

If anyone knows how to do it please explain your answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention case-sensitivity, so I'll assume that's not a factor.

For an entry in `A2`:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        LEN(A2) = 7,
        1 - ISNA(XMATCH(MID(A2, {1; 2; 5; 6; 7}, 1), CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 65)))),
        1 - ISERR(0 + MID(A2, {3; 4}, 1))
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

Comment: can you explain your code?

Comment: `LEN(A2) = 7` is self-explanatory. `1 - ISNA(XMATCH(MID(A2, {1; 2; 5; 6; 7}, 1), CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 65))))` checks that the 1st, 2nd, 5th, 6th and 7th characters are lower-case or upper-case a-z, `1 - ISERR(0 + MID(A2, {3; 4}, 1))` checks that the 3rd and 4th characters are numerics.

Comment: @Temp4Watch when you dont understand a formula, always try to break it part by part or, try to use the evaluate formula feature in excel under formulas tab.

Answer (score 0):

Jos' answer works perfectly well. This is longer but it may be easier for you to follow as I have used ISNUMBER and VALUE which I guess you are familiar with. Each character has to be checked individually. This checks that the string starts with 2 non-numbers, then 2 numbers, then 3 non-numbers:

```
=AND(
LEN(A2)=7,
NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,1,1)))),
NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,2,1)))),
ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,3,1))),
ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,4,1))),
NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,5,1)))),
NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,6,1)))),
NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A2,7,1)))))
```